# NextCloud get direct link of file

Tags: nextcloud

I installed nextcloud version 22 on my server and I need to go directly to files like nextcloud.com/folder/file.xls instead of going to the link nextcloud.com/folder/download.

I verified that there is SharingPath https://apps.nextcloud.com/apps/sharingpath but I can't activate it.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which kind of share are u addressing.
The public one could be access by `Sharing API` through the get method

```
https://(write_your_drive)/ocs/v2.php/apps/files_sharing/api/v1/shares
```

Add to Headers the OCS_API Header to true.
The second one has to be built from the first simply fetching the shared files fileid